# pandas OHLC aggregation resample with time of OHLC

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-resample

I am converting 1 minute candle to 5 minute candle as below:

```
df = df.resample("5min").agg({
'stock_name': 'first', 
'tr_open': 'first', 
'tr_high': 'max', 
'tr_low': 'min', 
'tr_close': 'last'
})
```

For some reason, I need the time when OHLC values were taken for this aggregation.

Meaning, tr_time_high should contain the time when the tr_high was HIGH in this 5min candle etc.

How can I achieve this in Pandas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you could show the head of the original dataframe and one example of what you hope to get it would be much easier getting an answer

Answer (score 1):

I prefer used `groupby_agg` instead `resample_agg` in your case to allow [naming aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#groupby-aggregate-named). Try:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5T')).agg(
   stock=('stock_name', 'first'),
   open=('tr_open', 'first'),
   high=('tr_high', 'max'),
   low=('tr_low', 'min'),
   close=('tr_close', 'last'),
   time_high=('tr_high', 'idxmax'),
)
```